# Xcode HTML document.getElementBy without ID and Name

Tags: javascript, html, ios, xcode, webkit

Hi I'm trying to get a button of a webpage with

```
 document.getElementBy...
```

The problem is that the button does not have an `Id` and also a `Name`.
I tried to use `getElementByClass('class')` but Xcode says that it's not a function, I also tried to use `getElementsByTagName('tag')[0]` but it retrieves nil.

this is the button html:

```
<input type="button" class="check-auth" value="Conferma" size="15" tabindex="4" style="border-radius: 5px;border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;background-color:#009245;color: #ffffff;height: 30px;font-size: 16px;padding-left: 4px;width: 105px;width: 113px;">
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` is the function for selecting the elements having certain class.

Comment: Show us the HTML of your button please

Comment: Try using `document.querySelector('your_css_selector')`

Comment: this is the Button HTML :      <input type="button" class="check-auth" value="Conferma" size="15" tabindex="4" style="border-radius: 5px;border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;background-color:#009245;color: #ffffff;height: 30px;font-size: 16px;padding-left: 4px;width: 105px;width: 113px;">

Comment: so, document.querySelector('.check-auth') should work :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector to find an element by its className. Just note that multiple elements can have the same className in the DOM and that querySelector will only get the first. You can also use querySelectorAll.

querySelector/querySelectorAll accepts any CSS selector as its param.

Since your className is check-auth, this should work:

```
var button = document.querySelector('.check-auth');
```